# Yarn 3 install/update dependency for all workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Is there a way to install/update dependency for all workspaces using Yarn 3?

Something like `yarn workspaces foreach add typescript -D -E`

Comment: I'm searching for this answer too

Answer (score 0):

`yarn upgrade-interactive` should show you results from all workspaces. You can then select the packages to update. Not ideal, but nor is a lot of the new things in Yarn 3.